# What is a "loopback", can it cause "damage"?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, loopback

The high school I attend won't allow students to have the WiFi password. Our entire education system is evolving and becoming more and more dependent on the internet. Therefore, I brought my own laptop with an Ethernet cable and adapter so that I could directly access the school's internet and work on assignments. The 'computer lab lady' saw me doing this one day and had a FIT about it. She started screaming at me to "remove that cable! It will cause a 'loop back'. " So naturally I asked what that is and she couldn't even answer it herself. So I've been doing research and decided explaining the situation is my best bet. To anyone who cares enough to read this paragraph, please explain to me why that lady got so upset about me plugging an ethernet cable into another computer. Will this harm the "system"? My Father is a computer engineer and gave me a completely different description of loop back than she did.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you plugging your laptop via Ethernet cable directly to the wall port? Or into another computer?

Comment: Plugging it into another computer.

Comment: May be she meant [Switching Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_loop).  But I don't see how that would happen in your scenario.

Comment: @AEonAX, if both PCs are plugged into the network and each other, if they are set to bridge mode (it was, at least at one time, the Windows default), you could create a spanning tree loop that could create a broadcast storm that brings down the network.

Comment: @RonMaupin Both PCs will require two network ports for that to happen?

Comment: @AEonAX, yes. It would not really be a common scenario, but it could happen. The laptops I buy now all have two ethernet interfaces, or it is a simple matter to connect a USB/ethernet interface.

Answer (score 0):

The loop back she mentioned means the network traffic just bounces around and amplifies between those two ports  <s>it can physically damage the ports and/or the network adapter</s> , this was a problem many years ago but now I must say this , most consumer network adapter are "idiot proof"

If you want details just google "what happens when two computers are connected via ethernet port "

Here is a link I found with a quick search describing the issue its old but informative

https://serverfault.com/questions/366072/what-happens-when-you-plug-two-sides-of-a-cable-to-a-single-networking-device

You must also know what is a patch cable and a crossover cable , patch cables are used when you want to connect to internet or a network (routers to PC) crossover cables are used to transfer information between 2 devices (computer to computer) you may have realised connecting the cable you didn't get any internet that's because you used it as a crossover cable. 
<s>When networking was nascent you would have physically damaged the ports of you had not used the right cable but now with technology being "idiot proof" the network adapter   automatically calibrates itself to work accordingly to prevent any damage or malfunction</s>

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

These days a feature knows as auto MDI-X is used to automatically connect the two devices.

The article which helped me understand why there wont be any damage
http://www.veracityglobal.com/resources/articles-and-white-papers/poe-explained-part-2.aspx

Quoted from the link above

> Myths and misconceptions
>
> POE is a recently-developed technology, and many people are put off
>   adopting it by the raft of conflicting or out-of-date information that
>   is available on the subject.  Here are the most common misconceptions:
>
> POE has compatibility problems. Not so. It is true that the early days
>   of POE, many home-brewed and proprietary schemes were employed to get
>   power over network cables.  However, the IEEE 802.3af standard has
>   gained universal adoption as POE's popularity has spread, meaning that
>   compatibility between all modern POE equipment is assured.
>
> POE requires electrical knowledge. Again, early ad-hoc implementations
>   may have required careful design, but IEEE 802.3af POE is designed to
>   ensure reliable operation in any configuration that would be possible
>   with regular Ethernet.  All the user has to do is wire up the network
>   as normal, and the equipment will take care of power delivery.
>
> POE requires special wiring. Not at all, the same cabling - Cat 5e,
>   Cat 6, etc - and "RJ45"-style connectors are used for both regular and
>   PoE-enabled local area networks.
>
> Power is forced into devices. This misconception is surprisingly
>   common, however it is important to remember that power ratings quoted
>   by manufacturers are upper limits and are not fixed.  Plugging a 5
>   watt camera into a 15 watt injector does not result in 10 watts of
>   power being lost somewhere; the camera will simply draw as much
>   electrical power as it needs.

Comment: I dispute that it would cause physical damage to anything. Do you have something to back this up?

Comment: @Darren you are right mate its an internet myth i believed in it for years , il edit the answer accordingly.